# Creating Google sitemap.xml , is it okay for the images to be wrapped in URL tags?

Tags: google, sitemap

I'm using a tool to generate the *sitemap.xml* file for me, it started to crawl my website, got the pages and all images, but when exporting it, I review the XML (to make sure nothing is wrong) and I noticed that the images in my website are wrapped in URL tags (I think it should be in image tags).
See this:

`<url><loc>http://mywebsite.com/images/12.jpg</loc><lastmod>2012-05-23T13:39:02+00:00</lastmod><changefreq>weekly</changefreq><priority>0.50</priority></url>`

Shouldn't it be wrapped in image tag? (just like videos wrapped in `video` tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look correct for images being listed in a sitemap, I would use another sitemap generator. The example below is from [Google's Webmaster Central blog post about adding images to your sitemap](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/adding-images-to-your-sitemaps.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
   xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

And more information can also be found here about image sitemaps http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636

Comment: Yeah images are better in a separate image sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

If the tool is inserting images into `loc` it is either very old or configured incorrectly or buggy :)

You should, like others have said create separate image sitemap, video sitemap etc. that features such content.